# Prove $\ker {T^k} \cap {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} {T^k} = \{ 0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$, a vector space of dimension $n$, and a linear operator $T:V\rightarrow V$.
>   Prove: $\forall k \ge n: \ker {T^k} \cap {\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} {T^k} = \{ 0\}$

For a start I chose $v \in$ the intersection. Therefore,
$T^k(v) = 0$ and there's $u \in V$ such that $T^k(u) = v$.

What to do next?
Also, I'd be glad if you could help me understand the meaning of the equality.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\ker T^k = \ker T^{k+1} = \ldots $ when $k =n $

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Benja, this is so because $\ker T\supseteq \ker T^2\supseteq\cdots$, and because of the finite dimension, the sequence of subspaces can't get strictly smaller forever. And also, if $\ker T^{j+1}=\ker T^j$ then $\ker T^{k+1}=\ker T^k$ for all $k\ge j$.

Comment: Your inclusion is the wrong way around I think.

Comment: Perhaps it could be noted that, taking into account the observation of @HaraldHanche-Olsen, this is part of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_lemma

Comment: @Edwardffitch Of course! How I wish for the ability to edit comments once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\ker T^i \subseteq \ker T^{i+1} \forall i \geq 1$. So we must have that $\ker T^k=\ker T^{k+1}$ for $k \geq n$, because dim$V=n$. Note that for any linear map $T:V \rightarrow V$, $0 \in \text{im} T \cap \ker T$. Now for the opposite inclusion, suppose $u \in \text{im} T^{k} \cap \ker T^{k}$, but $u \neq 0$. Then $\exists u' \in V \smallsetminus \ker T^{k}$ such that   $T^{k}(u')=u$. Now, $T^{2k}(u')=T^{k}(u)=0$ so $u' \in \ker T^{2k}=\ker T^{k}$, a contradiction. Hence $\text{im} T^{k} \cap \ker T^{k}={0}$ as required. $\square$

Comment: Yes, but there is a gap between the first and second sentence: All you get from the first inclusion is that there are at most $n$ *strict* inclusions in the sequence $\ker T\subseteq\ker T^2\ker T^3\subseteq\cdots$. You need an additional (easy!) argument that the strict inclusions are bunched up in the initial segment, after which all the kernels are equal.